# ROS Answers SE migration: UM6 Hanging

Tags: ros, clearpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using a CHR um6 imu on a Clearpath Robotics Husky A200. I am using Clearpath's um6 package to get data from the imu. When I send the command `rosrun um6 um6_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB1` the terminal tells me

> [ INFO] [1384801673.621856253]: Successfully connected to serial port.

> [ WARN] [1384801673.964338871]: Discarding packet due to bad checksum.

> [ WARN] [1384801673.966617365]: Discarded 13 junk byte(s) preceeding packet.

> [ INFO] [1384801673.990920390]: Sending command: zero gyroscopes

At this point it just hangs there. I ran `rostopic list` in another terminal tab, and none of the topics that um6 should be publishing appeared. Anyone else have this problem or know how to fix it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102341/um6-hanging/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-11-18**:
Which version of the package are you using?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-11-18**:
The latest one for Hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm the author of the package. Two quick suggestions:

First, confirm that your UM6 is indeed sending data. Check it with picocom, for example:

```
picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

It's binary output, but you should see `snp` packet headers in among the noise. Ctrl-A Ctrl-Q to exit from picocom.

Second, try turning on debug output for the node, which may give more clues as to what's gone wrong. Add the following line to `/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/config/rosconsole.config`:

```
log4j.logger.ros.um6=DEBUG
```

And then roslaunch the node with the `--screen` option.

---

To follow up, the structure of the`um6` driver is that messages all get published at once by the [publishMsgs function](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/um6/blob/hydro-devel/src/main.cpp#L159). This function only gets called when a trigger packet arrives. This has been set to be the temperature report, which the UM6 always publishes last in its output batch. It's possible that for some reason your UM6 doesn't produce that message, or the configuration string which is supposed to turn on the temperature output isn't getting set.

Do you know which version of the firmware you have? You may be able to [upgrade the firmware](http://www.chrobotics.com/docs/AN-1002-ReprogrammingUM6Firwmare.pdf) to a more recent version which would provide the temperature packet.

Alternatively, feel free to fork the driver on Github and provide a parameter which uses some other message to trigger the ROS publishers (for example, UM6_ERROR_COV_30, which is the one right before [UM6_TEMPERATURE](http://sourceforge.net/p/um6firmware/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/UM6%20Firmware/CHR_packet_handler.c#l571)).

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-11-19**:
Hi Mike,

I can see the headers when running picocom, and when I run with debug output on it says

> Received packet [hex #] with batched (2 or 4) data.

So it seems like data is being received. It still is not publishing any topics though when I run `rostopic list`.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-11-24**:
Hey Icehawk, I've updated my answer with some other suggestions; please take a look.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-11-25**:
Hey Mike, I am using UM1B. I shall update to the latest firmware. Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-11-25**:
Updated the firmware and ros is now publishing the topics. Thanks for your help Mike.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-11-26**:
Awesome, glad to hear!